# Log4j. Dropping logs into mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, log4j, log4j2

i would like to send my logs to some MongoDB collection. I seems i modified my Maven pom file properly (can't see any errors while making build) so i skip these stepshere. What i did next:

i added the following appender in my log4j2.xml:

```
<appender name="mongo" class="org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender">
            <param name="hostname" value="localhost"/>
            <param name="port" value="27017"/>
            <param name="databaseName" value="cab"/>
            <param name="collectionName" value="log"/> 
</appender>
```

added a logger in this file:

```
</Logger>
            <Logger name="eventlog" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="mongo"/>
</Logger>
```

somewhere in my code i create a logger:

```
public static  final Logger event = LogManager.getFormatterLogger("eventlog");
```

and try to call it:

```
event.info("log smth. just 4 me");
```

and i can't see anything in my db(

what am i doing wrong?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the necessary dependend libraries? 
   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/log4j-nosql/index.html